# KarateException Missing Property in path - JSON

Tags: json, karate

I was trying to match particular variable from response and tried as below. But im getting error saying `KarateException Missing Property in path $['Odata']`. My question is: how we can modify so that we won't get this error?

**Feature:**

```
And match response.@odata.context.a.b contains '<b>'
```

Examples:

```
|b|
|b1  |
|b2  |
```

**Response is**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "$metadata#Accounts",

    "a": [
            {
                "c": 145729,
                "b": "b1",
                "d": "ON",
            },
            {
                "c": 145729,
                "b": "b2",
                "d": "ON",
            }
        ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused with the structure of your JSON. Also note that when the JSON key has special characters, you need to change the way you use them in path expressions. You can try paste the below in a new Scenario and see it work:

```
* def response =
"""
{
"@odata.context": "$metadata#Accounts",
"a": [
    {
        "c": 145729,
        "b": "b1",
        "d": "ON",
    },
    {
        "c": 145729,
        "b": "b2",
        "d": "ON",
    }
]
}
"""
* match response['@odata.context'] == '$metadata#Accounts'
* match response.a[0].b == 'b1'
* match response.a[1].b == 'b2'
```

Comment: Actually this is a Odata response, and we enter URL in any browser, we get response. And in feature file i cant paste response as it is very big. Any other suggestion please. Or we cant give path in feature file?

Comment: @ManjulaM sorry I can't understand what you are asking for. I don't have any other suggestion, so you can wait for someone else to help.

Comment: Sorry, my question was for this type of response, apart from entering response in feature using def, do we have have any other solution? As response is very huge

Comment: @ManjulaM please. I have just pasted it as an EXAMPLE. in real life you will get the response automatically. you only need the last 3 lines. clear ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I got what i want using  below: * match response.a[0].b == 'b1'
* match response.a[1].b == 'b2'